# Prevent Ansible Synchronize module from creating a temp directory

Tags: ansible, rsync

I am using the [Ansible Synchronize module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html) like so:

```
- name: Synchronization of src on the control machine to dest on the remote hosts
  synchronize:
    src: http-checks/
    dest: "{{ datadog_path }}/conf.d/http_check.d/"
    delete: yes
    recursive: yes
```

After the playbook executes, a directory called `~core/` is created with this directory structure:

```
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── site.yaml
└── ~core
    └── .ansible
        └── tmp
            └── ansible-tmp-1528320500.98-124390628295059
                └── synchronize.py
```

**Question:** How do I prevent the directory from being created?

I can't find any reference to this tmp directory in the ansible docs or the rsync docs.

Comment: by `~core`, you mean ~/core, a folder called core in your home directory? can you provide info about your ansible version?

Comment: ...why? This is operating workfiles for ansible, isn't it?

Comment: @ilias-sp by `~core` I mean a directory in the same directory as my playbook. Will add more info.

Comment: @PaulHodges I am not understanding your question.

Comment: @EricFrancis glad to see you sorted it. i have ansible 2.5.2, and the problem is not reproducible, probably its related to 2.2 as the github issue says. my `ansible.cfg` file has the `remote_tmp` entry commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21562

It seems I need to add `remote_tmp` in `ansible.cfg`:

```
# ansible.cfg
...
remote_tmp = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
```